# Powershell WMI Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration EnableDHCP to Remove IP Gateway doesn't work

Tags: powershell, networking, wmi

I'll have some computers with 8 network adapters, but only one is configured with the routed VLAN.

To identify it, I wrote a little powershell script that is a loop that assigns the IP address, test the Gateway connectivity until it founds the correct interface.

But when I try to release the IP address using **enableDHCP** method it will never clears the IP Address nor the Gateway.
I already tried **releaseDhcpLease**, for individual or for ALL interfaces, but without result ...

I've tried some tricks published here -> https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/94f0f04a-1669-4276-b529-e68edffd9aff/how-to-remove-default-gateway?forum=winserverpowershell

But none works..

the only effective method for to release the IP configuration was using "**netsh command**", for example:

```
netsh int ipv4 -name='Ethernet 3' addr=172.22.33.123 gateway=all
```

How can I do the same using **Powershell + WMI** commands? I may invoke "netsh", but script becomes little more complex  than I desire.

Regards

Comment: Which version of `PowerShell`?  Is using `wmi` a requirement?  Also, what OS + version?

Comment: I was doing under WinPE10 environment, Powershell version claims to be powershell 5.1

Comment: Check out `Get-Command -Module NetTCPIP` and its associated cmdlets.

Comment: Winpe contains a limited number of modules, NetTCPIP is not included, that's was the reason that I'm using WMI commands. I've also tried Invoking CIM methods with the same results.

Comment: WinPE has what you put into it.

Comment: WinPe has the following packages to include on it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-add-packages--optional-components-reference . I may add other packages but not necessary all works as expected and aren't officially supported under WinPe.. And If I already have WMI to do it, why don't use it, although t it is not working like NetSH does, what is the difference?